# Копия функции отрабатывает моментально, а оригинал до 2 минут

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть функция, которую используют много народа и иногда она страшно тупит.

Если я создаю копию этой функции и выполняю ее эксклюзивно для себя в том запросе, где тупит исходная функция , то запрос выполняется моментально, а если со старой то 2 минуты.

В чем может быть проблема?

В MS SQL есть какие-то блокировки на уровне объектов?

Планы запросов строятся идентичные.

Внутри функции выполняются всякие соединения с таблицами и т п.

Может такое быть, что старая функция использовала какую-то старую статистику по таблицам, а новая функция получили обновленную статистику и работает быстрее?

**UPD**

Похоже дело не в статистике. Если поменять функции местами, то моя только что скомпилированная процедура начинает тупить, а старая процедура работает нормально...

Comment: Сброс кэша планов - `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` -  помогает?

Comment: _"Если поменять процедуры местами, то моя только что скомпилированная процедура начинает тупить, а старая процедура работает нормально"_  тогда дело может быть просто в кэшировании, первая честно отрабатывает, а вторая пользуется кэшем.

Comment: вопрос - что значит поменять местами? что меняется? может быть значение параметров, использование (или нет) необязательных параметров? или например изменился набор данных в используемых функцией таблицах? Или может быть разница во внешнем запросе, в котором возможно используется вызов этой функции

Comment: Была Func_1, которая тормозила и использовалась большим кол-вом народа. Я решил сделать Func_2(По структуре аналогичен) и выполнить в том запросе, где тормозила Func_1 и результат вернулся моментально. Потом я переименовал Funс_2 в Func_1, а Func_1 в Func_2. И опять начались томроза, так как функцией начали пользоваться много народа. Т.е похоже, что дело не в статистике

Comment: а кроме названия у функций чтото меняется еще? Такое впечатление, что дело в частоте использования, например - блокировки какой-то таблицы при попытке писать туда из одновременных вызовов этой функции разными клиентами. Когда клиентов отсек переименованием - проблема 'ушла'

Comment: однако если в двух вариантах функции кроме названия ничего не меняется и они одновременно включены, и со второй версией проблем нет, то эта версия не проходит

Comment: если будешь отвечать мне, то ставь перед ответом ссылку на меня:  @ale - чтобы я оперативно получил уведомление об сообщении, а не случайно его увидел, как сейчас (для уведомления автора сообщения это необязательно, он получает уведомления автоматом)

Comment: первые 2 комента - про кэширование - вероятнее всего решают проблему. На самом деле ты не меняешь функции местами (если это копии) - статистика привязана к имени, которое ты устанавливаешь старым

Comment: @ale , а разве статистика не привязывается к Object_id?

Comment: @iluxa1810 , да Вы правы, но вопрос - как переименовывается функция (при наличии такойже). конечно, может быть я ошибаюсь в предположениях

Comment: @ale А касательно блокировок, в фунции везде прописан Nolock. А внути функции выполняется JOIN на вьюху, которая так же имеет nolock, а потом выполняется некоторая логика с извлеченными значениями в переменные через IF else

Comment: @iluxa1810 ясно, тогда моих мозгов уже не хватает для решения. Хотя какаято  явная причина обязательно есть, что-то упускаете. Попробуйте все-таки сбросить кэш.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быстро ответить на ваш вопрос вряд ли получится, рекомендовал бы прочитать полезную статью про причины подобного замедления - если регулярно работаете с MS SQL, это может быть весьма полезно и познавательно:

http://www.somewheresomehow.ru/fast-in-ssms-slow-in-app-part1/